# how to set up open source wireless lan controlloer (wlc) to manage multiple access points

Tags: hostapd

I am working on linux devices to facilitate different functionalities (like access point, CAN controller, I2C, etc.). Due to financial limits,  we have planned to implement access points using linux supported wlan modules(running with hostapd). The ultimate idea is also to implement WLAN controller(WLC) features(authentication, handover, etc.) in a central unit like switch and to configure/controll access points with it.

However at the begining we would like to test WLC features of two access points directly attached with PC over ethernet interface. 
**But at the moment we are confused that:Is there any way to impliment wireless lan controller (linux based) for centralized management of  hostapd access points?**

Though, the CAPWAP protocol has been standardized by IETF for the communication between access points and wlan controler(WLC) but **Does hostapd support CAPWAP/LWAPP or not?**

please help us in this regard,

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: well no too much. i set up access points and radius server using hostapd, these are running. I googled alot about incorporation of CAPWAP in hostapd but could find clear answer. And now i dont know how to proceed to set up CAPWAP or even is it possible to incorporate it in hostapd or not? or is there any other way to do this?